# Setting a property without a setter. How is this not a compile error?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class

```
 public class Settings : ProviderSettings {
        internal Settings(MyProvider provider) {
            this.Provider = provider;
            LoadFromConfig();
        }

        protected override IProvider Provider {
            get;
        }
}
```

The ProviderSettings class is:

```
 public abstract class ProviderSettings {
          protected abstract IProvider Provider { get; }
 }
```

**In Visual Studio 2015 I don't get a compile error when I target .NET 4.0. I would imagine that I should have received a compile error saying that "Provider is read-only and can't be set". Why is the compiler allowing this?**

Comment: Quick question: how were you planning on ever setting the value in a property with a getter with no body?  What would you expect the result of using the getter to be?

Comment: using a backing field that I would set in the constructor and return using the getter.

Comment: And what happens when you write the code that way?

Comment: it works that way but I accidentally used the property and was surprised that the compiler didn't barf at me.

Comment: .NET version does not imply C# version. This is a C# 6 feature, which all code in VS 2015 will be compiled under. You can use it in .NET 2.0 if you wanted to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify setter, then backing field of getter-only auto-property is implicitly declared as `readonly`. You can initialize it from constructor or using property initializer. This is a new feature of C# 6.

So actually your code will be compiled as

```
public abstract class ProviderSettings
{
    protected abstract IProvider get_Provider();
    // there is no property setter
}

public class Settings : ProviderSettings
{
    private readonly IProvider _provider;

    internal Settings(MyProvider provider) {
        _provider = provider; // assignment directly to backing field
        LoadFromConfig();
    }

    protected override IProvider get_Provider()
    {
        return _provider;
    }
    // there is no property setter
}
```

Related part of [C# 6 Language Specification](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/classes.md#properties) (draft):

> If the auto-property has no set accessor, the backing field is
>   considered readonly. Just like a readonly field, a getter-only
>   auto-property can also be assigned to in the body of a constructor of
>   the enclosing class. Such an assignment assigns directly to the
>   readonly backing field of the property.

Comment: Which means that it can be set from the constructor, as in his example